# Remote file upload with selenium in typescript?

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I was wondering what's the way to handle remote file upload with selenium-webdriver in typescript?

In javascript, this bit of code works:

```
import remote from 'selenium-webdriver/remote';
// import * as remote from 'selenium-webdriver/remote'; // used for typescript

browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());
uploadElement.sendKeys(path.resolve(__dirname, f));
```

But in typescript, I'm getting `Property 'FileDetector' does not exist on type 'typeof remote'`. I have both `@types/selenium-webdriver` and `selenium-webdriver` installed already.

```
"@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.39",
"selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.1"
```

**Edit:** Update with suggestion from bcherny

```
import { FileDetector } from 'selenium-webdriver';

return fileDetector.handleFile(browser.driver, f).then((fPath) => {
  browser.setFileDetector(fileDetector);

  return uploadElement.sendKeys(path.resolve(__dirname, fPath))
}
```

**Edit:** Working code

```
import * as remote from 'selenium-webdriver/remote';

browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());
return uploadElement.sendKeys(path.resolve(__dirname, f))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code, had to import from the remote typings

```
import * as remote from 'selenium-webdriver/remote';

browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());
return uploadElement.sendKeys(path.resolve(__dirname, f))
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have did here?

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
import { FileDetector } from 'selenium-webdriver'
```

See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/76a710cc945a34dcf664ded78937c9b957b3eccd/selenium-webdriver/test/index.ts#L485

Comment: So I was a bit confused with that. In the typings for selenium-webdriver, it says to use selenium-webdriver/remote.FileDetector for remote upload

Comment: Did you try the code above, and does it work? The file I linked is the tests for the selenium-webdriver typings.